# How do I replicate this asymmetrical bevel?

Tags: modeling, mesh, bevel

I am rebuilding this mesh from scratch with primitives, but it has a bevel that is non-uniform:

[image]

[image]

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> on the top of a cylinder will add a uniform bevel across the whole top of the cylinder:

[image]

Any ideas how I would go about creating this type of bevel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

but bevel ( the destructive operator ) can do some cool stuff too.

1. make a cylinder, use the Knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd>) to cut a line at the right angle through the cylinder.

   - Press <kbd>Z</kbd> to set the mode to "*cut straight through*".
   - to make a straight cut: left click the start location, double left click at the final location to end the cut line. Hit Enter to finalize the cut.
2. inset a circle in the top, and drag it towards the side where you want the shortest radius. Then select the outer edges.

[image]

3. then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (bevel) and press <kbd>M</kbd> until the mode is *percent*. Then add segments using the mouse wheel.

look at the tool information bar at the bottom of the active 3dview.

[image]

[image]

---

If you can make it so all fillet edge pairs are similar in length, you'll get nice approximately "circular" fillets.

[image]